# onClick change background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I make my current script rotate between 3 defined colors or images to change out the body's background ?

Currently I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/VgM3e/

```
<button class="color">click to change color</button>



   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').on("click", function(){
         $(this).css({'background' : 'red'});
      });
   });
```

But I am having difficulty coming up with the logic to rotate between 3 defined colors or images. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: do you want a random color ?

Comment: No, just three predefined colors or src to images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check my fiddle...if this is what you want
http://jsfiddle.net/VgM3e/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var rotate = 0;
  var colors = ["blue","red","green"];
  $('body').on("click", function(){

     $(this).css({'background' : colors[rotate]});
      rotate++;
      if(rotate >= 3){
      rotate = 0;
      }

   });
});
```

Comment: That's perfect! Could this be done with background-image as well?

Comment: yes, change ```var colors = ["blue","red","green"];``` into var ```colors = ["url('img.jpg')","url('img2.jpg')","url('img3.jpg')"];```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var ex = 0;

  $('body').on("click", function(){
      ex = (ex+1)%3;
      if (ex == 0) { $(this).css({'background' : 'red'}) }
      else if (ex == 1) { $(this).css({'background' : 'green'}) }
      else { $(this).css({'background' : 'blue'}) }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var current = 0;
    $('body').on("click", function(){
        $(this).css({'background' : colors[current]});
        if (current >= colors.length - 1) {
            current = 0;
        }
        else { current++ };
    });
});
```

All you need to do is make sure there are valid color strings in the colors array. If you wanted to do background images you would just change the colors to urls (in string format, of course) and change the .css() function as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
i=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').on("click", function(){
switch (i)
{
case 0:
         $(this).css({'background' : 'red'});
        break;

case 1:
         $(this).css({'background' : 'green'});
        break;

case 2:
         $(this).css({'background' : 'blue'});
        break;
}
i++;
if(i==3)i=0;
      });
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/VgM3e/3/

Comment: That's perfect! Could this be done with background-image as well?

Comment: ofcourse , just use $(this).css({'background-image' : 'URL to YOUR IMAGE'});

Comment: but in my opinion using array is much better , i didnt think you would like this one !!